# Explanation of Givens rotation in Jacobi Rotation SVD

Tags: matrix, algorithms, svd

I'm trying to implement Singular Value Decomposition (homework of sorts) via the Jacobi Rotation method ([more info here, pages 11 and 12](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Einderjit/public_papers/HLA_SVD.pdf)).

I am stuck at the bullet saying (sorry for the picture, but I'm not too familiar with writing formulas... yet):

[image]

I know how to find the sine and cosine which rotate a vector (say, [as explained in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Givens_rotation#Stable_calculation)), but I don't understand the process above:

- how should I find `s` and `c` when `B` is a 2x2 matrix is involved (instead of a 2x1 vector, as in Wikipedia)?
- how should I find the `s-hat` and `c-hat` in the right matrix?

Comment: i believe this question already has an answer here: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/8899/33248

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question.